# Leaflet.js Map not showing any tiles

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary, leaflet

Here's the code for my leaflet :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
  var latlng = new L.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
  var map = L.map('map').setView(latlng, 11)
  L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    maxZoom: 18
  }).addTo(map);
  map.invalidateSize();
  var marker = L.marker(latlng).addTo(map);
  map.invalidateSize();
  map.on('click', function(e) {
    if (marker != undefined) {
      map.invalidateSize();
      map.removeLayer(marker);
    }
    marker = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
    var lat = marker.getLatLng().lat;
    var lng = marker.getLatLng().lng;

    var txt = lat.toString() + " , " + lng.toString();
    document.getElementById('cords').value = txt;
    document.getElementById('locationX').value = lat;
    document.getElementById('locationY').value = lng;

  });
  });
  </script>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px;"></div>
  </div>
```

When I run this code in my localhost, It works All good and fine. But when I Deploy it on my website, It doesn't show anything.
No errors show up in my console, and no map tile.
What seems to be the problem? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What browser(s) and version? Is your website served with https?

Comment: no it's not https, It's http. is it because of the ssl ? @ghybs

Comment: Browser is Chrome V69.0 @ghybs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome no longer allows geolocation API on non secure origins (i.e. if not served through https), except for localhost.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: Thank you for your Answer! @ghybs